# How best to make this flexbox 100% height without specifying fixed height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I want to space these 3 divs evenly in a column but their parent (`.outer`) won't go to 100% height of the other columns contents. I think because its parent doesn't have a fixed height set.

```css
.container{
  margin-top: 60px;
}
 .container{
  border: 1px solid #000;  
}
.outer{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.row-center{
  height: 100%;
}

.outer{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100%;
}

.one, .two, .three{
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x500"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 row-center">
      <div class="outer">
        <div class="one">some text</div>
        <div class="two">some text</div>
        <div class="three">some text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle mirror: https://jsfiddle.net/4mxfbody/2/

What is the best procedure here?  I have tried absolute positioning `.outer` but could not get it to work right.

Answer (score 3):

Nested flexboxes

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/4mxfbody/7/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.outer {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.row-center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex: 1;
}
.one,
.two,
.three {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x500">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 row-center">
      <div class="outer">
        <div class="one">some text</div>
        <div class="two">some text</div>
        <div class="three">some text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And if you replace `flex: 0 0 40px;` with `flex: 1`, each div expands to evenly fill the container. https://jsfiddle.net/4mxfbody/8/